# Is there any abstract variables in java?

Tags: java, variables, abstract

Can variables be `abstract` in Java? Do constructor support `abstract` variables? I am not sure but I think the constructor supports static variables. Please clarify my doubt.

Comment: If a variable can be `abstract`, just what do you think that means? Perhaps you should investigate your motivation.

Answer (score 25):

In java only classes and methods can be abstract. Variable declarations cannot. However you can have variable declarations whose types are abstract. See example:

```
public abstract class MyClass { // allowed
   public abstract myMethod(); // allowed
   public MyClass instance; // allowed

   public abstract MyClass instance; // NOT ALLOWED!!
}
```

Comment: I am Java beginner. How is this allowed. >>public MyClass instance; // allowed . Isn't that creating instance of a abstract class?

Comment: @goldenmean It's not yet instanced. public MyClass instance = new MyClass() would throw errors. (if MyClass is abstract)

Comment: `public abstract myMethod();` is throwing me errors that a datatype needs to be present

Answer (score 11):

The language specifacation lists 7 types of variables:

1. **class variables** - declared as static within a class declaration
2. **instance variables** - declared within a class declaration without using the static keyword
3. **array components** - like `i[2]` when we create an array like `int[] i= new int[5]`
4. **method parameters** - name argument values passed to a method
5. **constructor parameters** - name argument values passed to a constructor
6. **exception-handler parameter** - created each time an exception is caught
7. **local variables** - declared in a block (`{ }`) or for statement

You can use all variable types (except #4) in a constructor:

```
class Demo {
   static int demo1 = 0;               // class variable
   int[] demo2 = new int[5];           // instance variable
   Demo(int demo3) {                   // constructor parameter
     try {
       int demo4 =                     // local variable
                   demo2[2];           // array component
     } catch(RuntimeException demo5) { // exception-handler parameter
     }
     demo2 = new int[]{Demo.demo1};    // using class and instance variable
                                       // in a constructor
   }
   int method(int demo6) {             // method parameter
   }
}
```

The `abstract` keyword is not allowed for variable declaration.

Answer (score 0):

abstract is a non-access modifier in java applicable for classes, methods but not variables. It is used to achieve abstraction which is one of the pillar of Object Oriented Programming.

Comment: Do you have something new in your answer that did not mentioned in previous answers?

Comment: Then why must an implementer of Serializable define long SerialUID?